# How to sum up the records on an Object with respect to a Month

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

Hello there Salesforce experts,

I have an Object **Monthly_cc__c** where there are records flowing in for each country every month.
Below are the fields

1. ID is the record ID
2. Processing Date
3. Processing Year
4. Processing Month
5. Distributor__c is the Master-Detal relation ship with Account.
6. Operating Company (IND, AUS, GBR...)

Now for every record there are the below fields

1. Personal CC
2. Monthly CC

For each Operating company these results are being sent and for the same Processing date we have various records for different Operating companies.

I would like to sum up the Personal cc for January for us to not complicate our SQL query.

Please let us know a solution on how to accomplish this task.

Thank you.

The expected result would be

For January, 2017

1. Personal CC = sum(AUS,IND,GBR'S Personal CC)
2. Monthly CC = Sum(AUS,IND,GBR'S Monthly CC)

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of options here and final result also depends on whether your company uses currency management (is CurrencyIsoCode field present on all objects?).

This should be what you're asking for:

```
SELECT Distributor__c, SUM(Personal_CC__c) personal, SUM(Monthly_CC__c) monthly
FROM Monthly_CC__c
WHERE Processing_Year__c = 2017 AND Processing_Month__c = 1
GROUP BY Distributor__c
LIMIT 200
```

This should be bit more flexible:

```
SELECT Distributor__c, Processing_Year__c, Processing_Month__c, SUM(Personal_CC__c) personal, SUM(Monthly_CC__c) monthly
FROM Monthly_CC__c
GROUP BY Distributor__c, Processing_Year__c, Processing_Month__c
LIMIT 200
```

Read up about [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm), [GROUP BY & aggregate functions, GROUP BY ROLLUP()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm).
Your data looks to be bit artificially split into day-month-year. If you have real date fields there are ways to [GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm).

And last but not least - if this query results will be processed in Apex - you need to read about [`AggregateResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).

P.S. You should work on your questions. We're not writing code for you. What have you tried, what part you're stuck on? If you're completely new to salesforce and don't even know what to experiment with - start with [SQOL-related Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/search?keywords=soql)

Comment: Thanks I am trying to add a field on the Monthly_cc__c object rather than pull a SOQL query result. Thanks for your help. My question is not with respect to a report pull but a aggregated field.

Comment: I don't understand your scenario. You want to add up a value from multiple "monthly" and then what - just display it? Save same value to every single "monthly" record? And you want to do it manually (with a for loop, adding numbers to each other) rather than using the built-in SOQL functions for that?

Comment: I want to auto generate a field Say Jan -18 have the sum of all the January values in it. Where do I include the SOQL if I have to?

Comment: You don't autogenerate fields in SF, not unless you use special hacks that call Metadata API or Tooling API from Apex... I really don't get you. I think what you need is so-called "analytic snapshot" or maybe nightly batch that would be calculating "this month's totals" and saving values on Accounts (or "yearly" records). Normally I'd do it with a rollup summary fields but they must be deterministic (not based on TODAY() for example and you'd need it to figure out what's the current month). Either way - you need more details for business requirement before deep diving to code.